# How to use gData to create, update and delete Google Contacts? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, gdata, google-contacts-api

I'm new to iOS development and I'm building an iOS app that will sync iPhone's Addressbook contacts with Google Contacts using gmail. So far I have successfully implemented gtm-oAuth2, Google Contacts v3 and able to successfully fetch contacts from google. But Google Contacts seems to only fetch the contacts, not able to manipulate contacts directly as stated on [Google Contacts webpage](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) (under the "Contact Entry" heading).

> **Contact Entry:**
>
> The Google Contacts API allows manipulation of Contact Entry implementing the GData Contact kind element...

So now, I'm using [gData API](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client) with Google Contacts but I don't understand *how to use gData in order to create new contacts, update contacts and delete contacts.*

If anyone knows how can we use gData to manipulate Google Contacts in iOS then please respond. If you could refer to code samples, that would be helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Tools I'm using: xCode 7 with iOS 9 simulator

Comment: Sorry if I sound condescending, but to sync your iPhone contacts with Google, simply switch that on in your iPhone Settings - no need to build an app for it. Is this a school project maybe?

Comment: Yes, Its a school project. In future, will be publishing this app on github for those who are interested to learn about oAuth2, Google Contacts, gData.

Comment: Aha. I have no experience with gData, but the links that you provide describe in detail how to do the things that you ask for, even with extensive example code. It may help you if you edit your question to describe in more details what you have tried, and what is actually failing.